# D-Link DIR-615 intermittently fails to respect static DHCP address assignment

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp

I'm connected wirelessly to a DIR-615 wireless AP+switch+router. I get an address via DHCP and am able to connect, although sometimes getting the address takes a long time for some reason; and once in a while the connection sort of dies and no longer resonds, and I need to discoonect.

But - that's not my main problem. My problem is with the IP that's assigned to me: I've registered a static DHCP address assignment for my PC's MAC address. Now, sometimes I do get that IP assignment to me, but sometimes I get a different one! Also, if I disconnect and reconnect, sometimes I get a lease with the undesirable address again, sometimes I'm switched to the new address.

I experience similar behavior with a second computer of mine (Laptop vs. Deskto), so it's probably the DIR-615, not my individual machines, that is the problem.

Notes:

- The hardware revision is M1. The firmware version is 1.0.0.
- A related question: [D-LINK DIR-615 router keeps giving my wireless devices bad ip addresses](https://superuser.com/questions/39289/d-link-dir-615-router-keeps-giving-my-wireless-devices-bad-ip-addresses)

Comment: If you running Windows 10, there is option to randomize MAC address to keep "kinda" privacy. Router associating static DHCP base on MAC address, so probably it is a case. Also make sure your router isn't hacked: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-899/product_id-36917/D-link-Dir-615-Firmware.html

Comment: 1. Privacy is not an issue here, I want the fixed address. 2. What makes you think it might be hacked?

Comment: Sometimes, you gotta buy a better router. Throw that one away.

Comment: 1. It's not about privacy, but technical issue. Windows randomizing MAC address on WiFi that influence static DHCP mechanism. 2. Because if you would google "DIR-615 vulnerability" you would see countless firmware vulnerabilities regarding this router. Some hacks don't brake router's functionality, but some do. I see such hacked devices very often

Comment: Entirely opinion-based... but... the DIR-615 was a horrible bit of kit, even 10 years ago when it was new. Buy something better.

Comment: @Tetsujin: 1. It's not mine. 2. I think that model number is reused for some newer hardware, which may or may not be as bad.